# How to write a '?' in the path of a universal link?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

How can a question mark `?` be specified as part of the `paths` pattern in the `apple-app-site-association` file?

The path should match the URLs:

```
domain.com/?a
domain.com/?ab
domain.com/?abc
...
```

The following does not work:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<myAppId>",
                "paths": ["/\?*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution? we are stuck on the same issue

Comment: We changed the server path to not include a question mark, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported. [From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> Note that only the path component of the URL is used for comparison. Other components, such as the query string or fragment identifier, are ignored.

If you have access to the configuration of the server, you might want to try rewriting these as path-addressable, rather than query addressable resources, either by an alias, rewrite rule, or similar mechanism.

Comment: That's in fact supported, I have a link /mypath?param=2jhf and I just add /mypath to the app-app-site-association

Comment: @AntonioLabra yes, but now I see the questions was if you can add the character "?" on the  app-app-site-association file, which indeed you can't. In my case I added the path and the system recognized the params, which is pretty different

Comment: I don't know if you can help me. I have URL's like myDomain.mx/store?branch=StoreA and my Apple-app-site-association file has : { "/":"/store" }   is this ok?